# What is the meaning of "Steer 1-2-0" in WWII texts?

Tags: radio-communications, phraseology, wwii

I am reading some texts about WWII and English operators tell the pilots to "Steer 1-2-0". Can anyone help with the meaning of 'steer' here? Is it a synonym of 'direction', 'heading' or 'vector'?

Comment: If you would include some context, that would be immensely helpful. What books are you reading? Can you include some quoted (and properly attributed) text with context? Of course, someone may well know based simply on what you've provided, but you'll increase your chances of a good, accurate and quick answer by providing more background. Also, take the [tour] and read the [help] - it'll only take a couple of minutes and will get you acquainted with how things work here. Welcome to [Aviation.se]!

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/49270/62)

Answer (score 3):

To "steer" means to change the aircraft's track (the direction of movement of the aircraft) to a certain degree in relation to the lines of meridian (north–south lines). The units are degrees from north in a clockwise direction. North is 0°, east is 90°, south is 180°, and west is 270°. Note that, due to wind forces, track is not the same as the heading (where the nose is pointing).

Comment: Looks like there's some disagreement about whether "steer 120" refers to heading or track. Do you have a source showing that it refers to track?

Comment: With just a compass and no way of determining ground track via INS or GPS, I would wager it is the heading.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. '[to steer](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steer)' = 'to change course to', and the number is a compass heading. Source: reading lots of books on WW2. The term is still in use [on ships](https://www.thehulltruth.com/5133751-post60.html), not so much in aviation any more.

Answer (score 0):

The modern ATC phraseology is "Fly heading 1-2-0".

Comment: Looks like there's some disagreement about whether "steer 120" refers to heading or track. Do you have a source showing that it refers to heading?